# Vertical Text Placement in CSS Offset by Length of Text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an info tag that hangs off of a block element on a page but having some trouble getting the positioning right. To get the idea of what I'm trying to do, see the attached image. The content block is actually a right side column on the page.

[image]

```
<div class="contentblock">
  <span class="tag">tag</span>
</div>

div.contentblock{
  width: 575px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  min-height: 300px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
  ...
}

span.tag{
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: 495px;
  color: rgba(65,65,66,0.6);
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 115px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  margin-bottom: -145px;
  min-width: 60px;
  width: auto !important;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  border: 2px solid rgba(65,65,66,0.5);
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

This sort of works - the attached image is actually the result of that, but it doesn't work very well because the horizontal placement of the tag seems to be affected by the length of the tag. Longer text in the `<span pushes>` it off to the right (it also expands it vertically downward - as it should). Hence the semi-arbitrary margin-left on the tag element - that just happens to work for one particular string of text.

I think I'm going about this the wrong way. What would be a more effective way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not specifying a transform origin, it is defaulting to the middle of the element. As a result, changing the amount of text will offset the middle and cause the transformation to change.

You should specify a `transform-origin` (and all the vendor extensions) to something fixed, such as the top-left corner, and then position based on that.

Note that `-ms-transform` is perfectly functional too.

Comment: I had actually thought of this just after posting the question - this worked perfectly! Each additional character pushed the origin of the rotate further to the right - hence the issue. transform-origin: top-left; works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Might I suggest that you use CSS2 to position the tag at the top of the element, and then use the CSS3 `transform` to `translate` the element to the right? This will allow for graceful degradation on older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using margins to position the tag, try setting its 'right' property to a negative amount. Eg, right: -10px. That'll put it so that the tag's right edge is 10px to the right of the block's right edge.

Comment: I agree in general, though for whatever reason in this particular case it puts the tag in the middle of the box. Probably some other width issues.